# What is the command to change a Windows folder view

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, windows-explorer

I want to open Windows Explorer from the the command prompt, and displaying the contents as thumbnails.  The first part of this is easy:

```
explorer, dirname
```

How do I programmatically change the folder view?

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the view would need some registry edit.
Options for `explorer.exe` are listed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1039592.html) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't suppose you have any idea which registry values need editing, do you?